# Adjusting legend's spacing to main plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, legend-properties

[This topic](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Legend-Attributes) covers almost all attributes of legend in R. I'm wondering how we can increase the spacing between the legend and the main plot.

Comment: Take a look at `?theme` and `legend.margin`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following the example in the link you provided:

```
library(ggplot2)
xy <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=10:1, type = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each=5))
plot <- ggplot(data = xy)+
geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y, color=type))
```

[image]

```
plot <- plot + theme(legend.box.margin = margin(0, 0, 0, 20))
```

[image]